# Ory Kratos settings flow not successfully changing password

Tags: vue.js, ory, kratos

I have created my own UI for the [Ory Kratos](https://www.ory.sh/kratos/) settings flow. The problem I am having is that after submitting the flow, although the returned messages say that my settings have been updated successfully, my new password is not reflected and I haven't successfully recovered my account. Here is a snippet of the code I am using to render the UI with Vue 3.

```js
// SettingsVue.vue
<template>
  <div id="settings">
    <HomeTopbar :views="[]" />

    <div class="settings-wrapper">
      <h1 class="poppins fs_3 fw_6">Recover your password</h1>
      <OryFlow v-if="settingsFlow"
        :flow="settingsFlow"
        title="Login"
        form-id="settings-form"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

/* ory */
import { injectStrict } from '@/utils';
import { $ory } from '@/plugins/ory';
import { makeHandleGetFlowError } from '@/utils/flows';

/* types */
import type { SelfServiceSettingsFlow } from '@ory/kratos-client';

/* composables */
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';

/* components */
import OryFlow from '@/components/flows/OryFlow.vue';
import HomeTopbar from '@/components/ui/HomeTopbar.vue';

const ory = injectStrict($ory);
const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();
const settingsFlow = ref<SelfServiceSettingsFlow | undefined>();
const handleGetFlowError = makeHandleGetFlowError(router);

// check if we have a flow param
const { flow } = route.query;

const initializeSelfServiceSettingsFlowForBrowsers = () =>
  ory
    .initializeSelfServiceSettingsFlowForBrowsers()
    .then((response) => {
      settingsFlow.value = response.data;
      router.replace({
        query: {
          flow: response.data.id,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch(handleGetFlowError);

if (typeof flow !== 'string') {
  // if there's no flow in our route,
  // we need to initialize our login flow
  initializeSelfServiceSettingsFlowForBrowsers();
} else {
  ory
    .getSelfServiceSettingsFlow(flow)
    .then((response) => {
      settingsFlow.value = response.data;
    })
    .catch(handleGetFlowError);
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
#settings {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  .settings-wrapper {
    margin: var(--space-5) auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 var(--space-3);
    margin-top: var(--space-4);
    width: 300px;
  }
}
</style>
```

```js
#OryFlow.vue
<template>
  <div class="ory-flow">
    <form :id="formId" :action="flow.ui.action" :method="flow.ui.method">
      <OryUiNode v-for="node in flow.ui.nodes"
        :key="getNodeId(node)"
        :id="getNodeId(node)"
        :node="node"
        class="ui-node"
      />
    </form>
    <div class="messages" v-if="flow.ui.messages">
      <OryUiMessage v-for="message in flow.ui.messages" :message="message" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type {
  SelfServiceLoginFlow,
  SelfServiceRegistrationFlow,
  SelfServiceRecoveryFlow,
  SelfServiceSettingsFlow,
  SelfServiceVerificationFlow,
} from '@ory/kratos-client';
import OryUiNode from './OryUiNode.vue';
import OryUiMessage from './OryUiMessage.vue';
import { getNodeId } from '@ory/integrations/ui';

defineProps<{
  flow:
    | SelfServiceLoginFlow
    | SelfServiceRegistrationFlow
    | SelfServiceRecoveryFlow
    | SelfServiceSettingsFlow
    | SelfServiceVerificationFlow;
  formId?: string;
}>();
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.ui-node + .ui-node {
  margin-top: var(--space-2);
}

.message {
  margin-top: var(--space-2);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to this was actually pretty straight-forward and obvious after I reviewed the source code of the [selfservice ui for React](https://github.com/ory/kratos-selfservice-ui-react-nextjs) created and maintained by the Ory team.

If you submit all of the UI node groups together in the same form, it will only execute on the `default` group and one other group. In my case, it was disregarding the `password` group after successfully handling the `profile` group. The solution I followed was essentially the same as that provided in the repository I mention in the previous paragraph. Implement a filtering mechanism which will allow you to use two separate forms and thus separate those values at the time the form is submitted. *Bear in mind you must always submit the `default` group as it includes your CSRF token*.

Here is the updated code which solved my issue:

First, add support for an `:only` prop which will filter your nodes:

```js
// OryFlow.vue now with support for filtering via 'only' prop
<template>
  <div class="ory-flow">
    <form :id="formId"
      :action="flow.ui.action"
      :method="flow.ui.method"
    >
      <OryUiNode v-for="node in nodes"
        :id="getNodeId(node)"
        :key="getNodeId(node)"
        :node="node"
        class="ui-node"
      />
    </form>
    <div v-if="flow.ui.messages"
      class="messages"
    >
      <OryUiMessage v-for="message in flow.ui.messages"
        :key="message.id"
        :message="message"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import type {
  SelfServiceLoginFlow,
  SelfServiceRegistrationFlow,
  SelfServiceRecoveryFlow,
  SelfServiceSettingsFlow,
  SelfServiceVerificationFlow,
} from '@ory/kratos-client';
import OryUiNode from './OryUiNode.vue';
import OryUiMessage from './OryUiMessage.vue';
import { getNodeId } from '@ory/integrations/ui';
import { computed, toRefs } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  flow:
    | SelfServiceLoginFlow
    | SelfServiceRegistrationFlow
    | SelfServiceRecoveryFlow
    | SelfServiceSettingsFlow
    | SelfServiceVerificationFlow;
  formId?: string;
  only?: string | string[];
}>();

const { flow, only } = toRefs(props);

const nodes = computed(() => {
  if (!only?.value) {
    return flow.value.ui.nodes;
  }

  const onlyArr: string[] = Array.isArray(only.value) ? only.value : [only.value];
  const onlyMap = onlyArr.reduce((acc, curr: string) => {
    acc[curr] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, boolean>);

  return flow.value.ui.nodes.filter((node) => onlyMap[node.group]);
});
</script>
```

Next, utilize this new prop to filter only node groups `password` and `default` in one of your forms. You can use the same method to filter for `profile` and `default` in another form.

```html
// SettingsView.vue
<template>
  <div id="settings">
    <HomeTopbar :views="[]" />

    <div class="settings-wrapper">
      <h1 class="poppins fs_3 fw_6">Recover your password</h1>
      <!-- add the only prop here -->
      <OryFlow v-if="settingsFlow"
        :flow="settingsFlow"
        title="Login"
        form-id="settings-form"
        :only="[ 'password', 'default' ]"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```